# accessing remote spring batch jobs from spring batch admin

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am new to spring batch.                                                             I want to run spring batch jobs on server a and want to launch those jobs from server b using spring batch admin.is it possible? I have searched the following two ways:

1.JMX way: i could convert spring batch beans into mbeans but i cant read them from spring batch admin.can you tell how to read mbeans from spring batch admin and launch them?

2.common repository: i think if i use the same db repository for both spring batch and spring batch admin then i can launch remote jobs from spring batch admin (from server b).but in the job xml file in spring batch admin what should be the classpath for tasklet?

can you help in the above or tell me if any new way exists?

Answer (score 1):

we ended up implementing a framework using mq communication to handle this.  each 'batch node' registers itself and any 'batch class' parameters such as 'nodeType=A' or 'jobSizeiCanHandle=BIG' (these are fictitious but you get the point).  The client console reads this information and queries the nodes via MQ for the job list.  It then submits job requests with parameters via a rudimentary text based protocol (property file format).

```
command=START_JOB
job=JobABC
param1=x
param2=y
```

One of the batch nodes will pick up the message and start the job, it will return success/fail status in the same manner with a message with the same correlation id. so the client can show response to the user.

this allows us to do what you're talking about AND spark the jobs via an external scheduler (Control-M) .  The 'nodeType=A' mentioned above allows us to query individual nodes (the nodes listen where 'nodeType=A or nodeType=*'.  This allows commands to be 'targeted' to specific nodes if that is necessary.

Keep in mind, this is our own console, not the spring batch admin console. So perhaps that doesn't help you, but building up a simple console doesn't take that long using the spring batch APIs (4 or 5 asps).

The batch nodes could also have started up simple services like HTTP REST services or 'whatever' but we use MQ heavily and i liked the idea of not having to preregister nodes (the framework code doesn't know/care that it's in an HTTP container, so it couldn't register the endpoint easily). With MQ, the channel is preconfigured and all apps just 'use it' so it seemed easier.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing. But it seems that in order to launch job directly from Spring batch admin, all the job resource has to be added to the spring batch web app. May be try restful job submission with spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

@chau

One way to use Spring batch admin as is, but "discover" and "invoke" remote jobs is to provide your own implementations for org.springframework.batch.admin.service.JobService and org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator that can query and invoke jobs from remote job registry/repository.

You can find custom implementation for JobService and JMX enabled Job administrator in : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/tree/master/batch-core as: org.trpr.platform.batch.impl.spring.admin.SimpleJobService and org.trpr.platform.batch.impl.spring.jmx.JobAdministrator

Spring beans XML that uses these beans are here : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/blob/master/batch-core/src/main/resources/packaged/common-batch-config.xml